# How to setup test data when testing Firestore in XCode with Firebase Emulator?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have been trying to setup Firebase Emulator with test data for days.

### What I have done?

- I have successfully deployed Firebase Emulators
- I have written a test which checks for a value in the emulated Firestore and the test passes as well.

```
func test_WhenPartyNameIsUnique_ThenErrorIsNil() {
   // given
   let exp = self.expectation(description: "Waiting for Firebase Emulator")

   // when
   self.sut.isUnique(partyName: "akshit") { (error) in
     // then
     XCTAssertNil(error)
     exp.fulfill()
   }

   self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil)
}
```

### What's the problem?

I am not able to figure out how would I set up different test data for each of the tests. For the above test, I want to check if the partyName is not unique (meaning already present in the database). How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but the common way to get data into the emulators right now is to run code to inject that data from your application code at startup. Work is underway on a way to inject data on startup as a command line option to the emulators, but as usual: we can't make any promises, nor give a timeline. Until that lands it'll have to come from your code.

Comment: HI, @FrankvanPuffelen I want to set up the Firestore with some initial data, just for a specific unit test. I hope this is clear now.

Comment: In that case: the common way to get data into the emulators right now is to run code to inject that data from your application code at startup.

Answer (score 6):

The Firestore emulator now supports import/export.  So to create the a test case:

1. Run the emulators (`firebase emulators:start`)
2. Connect your app or a script and create the test data you want
3. In another terminal window run `firebase emulators:export ./some-directory`

Now you will have a snapshot of Firestore emulator data in `./some-directory`.  You can start the emulators with that data by running:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./some-directory
```

Right now this only supports Firestore but we hope to add import/export to more emulators using the same flow in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to export the data from production firestore and import it into the emulator like the above?

Comment: How might one access the imported data in a unit testing environment? That is, when using @firebase/testing, we typically create the test app like so:
`const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth }).firestore();` - how can one access the data imported thru the emulator and feed it into this db instance?

Answer (score 1):

The common way to get data into the emulators right now is to run code to inject that data from your application code at startup.

Work is underway on a way to inject data on startup as a command line option to the emulators, but as usual: we can't make any promises, nor give a timeline. Until that lands though, the test data will have to be inserted from your code typically in the setup of the tests.

Comment: Okay. But, can we have different Firestore states for different unit tests? I don't want to inject a single database at the beginning and then operate on that. It does not work well with all the test cases.

Comment: Most unit testing frameworks have a way to run dedicated setup methods for related test methods. I'm not a iOS expert, but this sounds very similar to other testing frameworks I've worked with: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods. With that out of the way, you'll want to choose whether to run a separate emulator run for each state, or run them all in a single run. I'd choose the latter, but in that case you'll need to make sure the test data is isolated (into collections for example) per state.

Comment: I would also choose the latter, run all the test with the single emulator instance. I also know about setup and teardown functions. What I was not sure about is how can I insert data to Firebase from the test target. But, as per your comments, I will have to change production code to have the ability to insert some test data and then call those functions from within the test target.

Comment: See my answer above for how to do import/export from files.

Comment: There's an answer from Sam that shows how to import data on startup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61501928