# How to inject data imported by Firestore emulator into db instance

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I know that we can now [export and import data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61501928) with the Firestore emulator.

How might one access the imported data in a unit testing environment? That is, when using `@firebase/testing`, we typically create the test app like so:

```
const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth}).firestore();
```

**How can one access the data imported thru the emulator and feed it into this db instance?**

My use case is for running unit tests on firestore rules against the imported data (for reference, the desired setup is very similar to this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953365/how-to-mock-data-for-testing-firestore-with-emulator), but instead of relying on a manually built mock object, I'd like to use data coming from the emulator export/import feature)

Here is my test file

```
/**
 * unit tests for firestore security and data validation rules
 *
 * adapted from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing/blob/master/unit-test-security-rules
 */
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path")

/**
 * The emulator will accept any project ID for testing.
 */
const PROJECT_ID = "test-dev-project";

/**
 * The FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is set automatically
 * by "firebase emulators:exec"
 */
const COVERAGE_URL = `http://${process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST}/emulator/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}:ruleCoverage.html`;

/**
 * Set up mock data
 */
const mockUser = {
  uid: 'alice',
  email: 'alice@example.com',
  company: 'testCompany'
}

/**
 * Creates a new client FirebaseApp with authentication and returns the Firestore db instance.
 * @param {object} auth the object to use for authentication (typically {uid: some-uid})
 * @param {object} data the test data to use for filling the db
 * @return {object} the firestore instance db .
 */
getAuthedDb = async (auth, data) => {
  // initialize test app
  const app = firebase.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth });
  let db = app.firestore();
  return db;
};

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Clear the database between tests
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
});

before(async () => {
  // Load the rules file before the tests begin
  const rules = fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8");
  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, rules });
});

after(async () => {
  // Delete all the FirebaseApp instances created during testing
  // Note: this does not affect or clear any data
  await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map((app) => app.delete()));
  console.log(`View rule coverage information at ${COVERAGE_URL}\n`);
});

function printDoc(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      console.log(`Document ${doc.id} data:`, doc.data());
  } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log(`No such document: ${doc.ref.path}, parent: ${doc.ref.parent.id}`);
  }
}

describe("Test Security Rules", () => {
  it("fetches data imported from emulator", async () => {
    const db = await getAuthedDb({uid: 'abcd'});
    const ref = db.doc("testdata/ac7yWTZekvGJMQj6Zq3M");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(ref.get().then(printDoc));
  });
});
```

When I run `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore --import=data/ "yarn run test-rules"` (`test-rules` maps to `mocha --timeout 10000 test/test.spec.js`), the assert succeeds but the doc `"testdata/ac7yWTZekvGJMQj6Zq3M"` is not found, yet it exists in the data I'd imported from `data/`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is the problem:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  // Clear the database between tests
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
});
```

Before each test is executed it’s going to fully clear out the emulators data. Big mistake on my part, the solution was to remove that code altogether, since my test data doesn't need to change between test cases